# PHP - Printing Alignment - For Receipt Printer from text file

Tags: php

I am creating a text file with the following code:

```
$textcreate = "**************************************\r\n" . PHP_EOL;            
$textcreate .= "Item             Amt     Qty     Total" . "\r\n" . PHP_EOL;
if (isset($print_table_for_txt_file["ordereditems"])) {
    foreach ($print_table_for_txt_file["ordereditems"] as $key => $value) {
         $textcreate .= $value['item_name'] . " " . number_format((float) $value['withoutTax_itemPrice'], 2, '.', '')  . "\r\n" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$textcreate .= "**************************************\r\n" . PHP_EOL;
$textcreate .= "Amount Payable:             " . round($print_table_for_txt_file['api']['0']['GrandTotal']) . ".00\r\n" . PHP_EOL;
$textcreate .= "**************************************\r\n" . PHP_EOL;

$myfile = fopen("example.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $textcreate);
```

The output of the file is :

************************************** Item      Amt     Qty     Total   pen  10.00    1     10.00 ************************************** Amount Payable:             10.00 **************************************

But I want the output to be :

```
************************************** 
Item             Amt     Qty     Total   
pen             10.00     1      10.00
************************************** 
Amount Payable:                  10.00 
**************************************
```

What should I do

Answer (score 3):

Browser shrinks all consecutive whitespaces (including `\r` and `\n`) in HTML into a single space. You can:

- use `header('Content-Type: text/plain')` to make the browser treat the output as plain text (leaving all whitespaces as they are)
- use the `<pre>` HTML tag to achieve the same in HTML

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply.  But in my case, i am writing directly to a text file. There is no HTML rendering.

Comment: How do You open that generated file? Is the file missing the newlines in it?